# How to blur ALL elements behind a div (text, shapes, buttons - not just the background image). CSS only if possible

Tags: html, css, blur

I am trying to blur everything that goes behind my navbar as you scroll, not just the background image. Using `backdrop-filter: blur(50px);` just blurs the background (including changes made by divs with other background filters), but leaves text untouched.

I have tried using `backdrop-filter: blur(50px);` as said above, `filter: blur(50px);` which just blurs the content, and looked at a dozen similar posts and websites. All of them either just tell me how to blur the background, or predate `backdrop-filter`.

Here is what I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/o3fks7dn/2/

EDIT: It appears that my `position: fixed;` also doesnt work, and nothing on the internet helps with that either, but thats not the point of this post.

Here is an updated fiddle using `position: sticky;`: https://jsfiddle.net/foqhrsgx/

Comment: `backdrop-filter` does exactly what you want: and its working in your fiddle, so I'm not sure what issue you are experiencing?

Comment: it gives a bit of a blurred glow around the text, but does not blur the text by 50 px like it is supposed to

Comment: Remove `backdrop-filter` from your `<body>` element: it doesn't do anything (and in fact, it may cause issues with Chrome)

Comment: it blurs the background image i have in my real version, the fiddle doesnt have the image https://imgur.com/a/AUFWyY6

Comment: If you want to blur the background image... add it as a pseudo-element to the body and blur it instead.

Comment: i do not know what a pseudo element is, how would that make a difference

Comment: Add a pseudo element and use `filter: blur(...)` on it. What is a pseudo element? Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements. How would that work? It seems like Chrome has a bug with backdrop filter applied directly to the body element. A pseudo-element is rendered as a separate element.

Comment: ok
why do i need to do that, how does it make a difference?

Comment: Also, if you want a blurred body background image, maybe just pre-blur it as such instead of relying on the browser to do that. Nothing goes "behind" the body anyway.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can get a mobile browser to crash just through this one filter ;) A 500px blur filter over the entire <body>! The memory consumption alone. And all that just to get a soft radial gradient as a background? Really? At least that's all I can see in the image you've linked.

Comment: i mean i do wanna try it on my phone now :)
the performance didnt seem bad when using the performane tools in ms edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I blurred by background image externally, and then took out the blur in css (as people told me to for performance reasons in the comments).

After doing that, and without changing anything else, now my blur works on the navbar! It seems to be that the background blur was messing up a bunch of stuff.

Thank you for the help in the comments!

P.S. The fixed positioning that didn't work before now works?!?